# Multiple instances of chromium browser

Tags: chromium

When I start chromium with proxy, the rest of these instances would use a proxy as well.

Is there a way to run multiple instances together? Just that chromium doesn't act like firefox, that you could decide which site should go through a proxy, and which shouldn't do that. (I run xfce4, and uses command line option to activate the proxy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lack of embedded proxy controls has been one of the complaints of Chrome and Chromium, which is why I still rely on good ole' Firefox for this sort of thing. The developers simply decided to leave it up to the operating system to handle proxying, which sort of creates a problem when you want to run a proxy for BitTorrent, whose short-sighted developers also came to the same lackluster conclusions. This is one area where Firefox is still clearly superior.

However, the Chromium platform exposes a Chrome Proxy API for extensions, which allows extension developers to create cool Chrome extensions that solve this problem. Out of the ones that I see in the Chrome Web Store, [Proxy SwitchySharp](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-switchysharp/dpplabbmogkhghncfbfdeeokoefdjegm) stands out because the description says it uses the API instead of modifying the system settings.

This means that, with this extension installed, you can define which sites go through a proxy and which don't, and at the same time only limit the proxy to affecting that one instance of the Chrome/Chromium browser.

As an aside, for the developer wishing to learn more about the API, see [Google Chrome Extensions - chrome.proxy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/proxy.html)

Answer (score 3):

Create plural Chromium profiles.

```
mkdir 1
chromium --user-profile-dir=1
```

Chromium will launch a separate instance if there are no running instances in the same profile directory.

Comment: I had to use `HOME=1 chromium-browser` instead of `--user-profile-dir`, but the concept worked. Thanks.